# How do we achieve the following using replace function in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, append

Transform

```
Source: This is source 1
Description : This is the description of source 1
Source: This is source 2
Description : This is a description of source 2
```

into this:

```
Description : This is a source 1: This is the description of source 1
Description : This is a source 2: This is the description of source 2
```

All the examples I have seen append line 2 to line 1 like this:

```
(^Source.*$)(\r\n)
\1
```

I need to append line 1 to line 2, and line 3 to line 4 etc.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Source(:.+)\R(Description\h+)`
- Replace with: `$2$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
  Source            # literallly
  (:.+)             # group 1, colon and 1 or more any character but newline
  \R                # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
  (                 # group 2
    Description     # literally
    \h+             # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  )                 # end group 2
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2              # content of group 2
$1              # content of group 1
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]